# Updating a date format in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date-format

I am working on a table that has two formats of dates stored in a field some are in `mm/dd/yy` and the newer entries are in `yyyy/mm/dd` like they should be.

I want to run an query like this

```
UPDATE table
   SET date_field = DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%Y/%m/%d') 
WHERE date_field = DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%m/%d/%y')
```

But it is just not working out. One result that I got was that it was just taking the `%m` data and turning it into the `%Y` and really messing up the data.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what's the column type of date_field? if it's date, or timestamp -- you cannot reorder Ymd to mdy

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want to use STR_TO_DATE function, not DATE_FORMAT. Plus, I assume you only want to update the misformed dates, so I guess you could do this :

```
UPDATE your_table
SET date_field = DATE(STR_TO_DATE(date_field, '%m/%d/%Y'))
WHERE DATE(STR_TO_DATE(date_field, '%m/%d/%Y')) <> '0000-00-00';
```

P.S. Tables contain *columns*, not fields. And you shouldn't use a string type to hold your dates, but the DATE type

Comment: Thanks, that should get that straightened out very well. Then we can move forward to get the rest of the site straightened out. It went from ASP to PHP and MS SQL to MySQL! It is amazing that it is still standing! Ha!

Answer (score 9):

You want to use [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to first convert the incorrect string to a real date object, then use `DATE_FORMAT` to turn it back into a string of the format you want.

Also, your `WHERE` condition won't work like that. You should be looking for strings of the wrong format using `LIKE`.

```
UPDATE your_table SET date_field =
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date_field, '%m/%d/%y'), '%Y/%m/%d') 
WHERE date_field LIKE '__/__/____'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thoughts? Ah yes, three actually:

- **don't reinvent the wheel**. Yes, yes, I know it's tempting to do from scratch what only a million of people have invented before (no sarcasm intended), but MySQL has a good, efficient, and usable `DATE` format, use that; only do the formatting on the input/output. That lets you avoid these kind of mixups of data (the date itself) and presentation (date format).
- As for the data, restore the known-good backup (you have backups, right?) - in the general case, **there's no fool-proof way to tell** unconverted y/m/d from already-converted m/d/y and the dates are f***ed for any practical purposes. (especially not in 2010 - e.g. `08/10/09` can mean several valid dates).
- Also, what kind of idea is it to only store 2 digits of the date? That's exactly the kind of short-sighted penny-pinching that has brought about the time- and money-sink that was Y2K. (avoided if you'd store the date, y'know, in a date format).