# mySQL - How to change date format from dd-mm-yy to yy-mm-dd?

Tags: mysql, database, date, formatting, date-format

I have some dates in my DB in the format of dd-mm-yy and some in yy-mm-dd

I want them all to be in yy-mm-dd

They are stored in VARCHAR fields

Examples dates are:

2011-10-19 and 19-10-2011

Is there a query to run to update to any that are not in this format?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you storing your dates? Which type of field? ANyway, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259729/updating-a-date-format-in-mysql

Comment: How can you tell which format they're in? Like, for example, `09-10-11`: is that 9 Oct. 2011, or is it 2009 Oct. 11?

Comment: Updated the post ruakh :) Cheers Nobita - looks spot on

Comment: Cheers Nobita - I did it with the code in that post :) UPDATE users
SET registration_date = DATE(STR_TO_DATE(registration_date, '%Y-%m-%d'))
WHERE DATE(STR_TO_DATE(registration_date, '%d-%m-%Y'));

Answer (score 3):

Dates are stored as dates, presumably you have strings.

If they are already actually dates just use `DATE_FORMAT` as needed.

If they are strings, your best option would be to **change them to actual dates** and store the date value in a new column.  Otherwise, down the road you will continue to have a lot of issues to deal with as Tony noted (+1 Tony!).

You can then populate it with `STR_TO_DATE`, e.g.

```
update tbl set new_date_field =
select STR_TO_DATE(string_date_field,'%y-%m-%d') ` # if string_date_field is '2011-01-01'
WHERE string_date_field RLIKE "^[0-9]{2}-";
```

Once you have a real date you can display it with `DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%y-%m-%d')`

The only other option if you can't add the field is to do string manipulation, i.e.
`Update table set date_field =

  substr(string_date_field,7,2) + '-' + substr(string_date_field,3,2) + '-' + substr(string_date_field,0,2)
    WHERE string_date_field RLIKE "^[0-9]{2}-";`

even this way I would still recommend a new field.

Note: if you need to do it in even more steps, say you can't change the population of the 'date as string' field immediately you could also put in a post insert / post update trigger (which mySQL now supports) to do the conversion (from the string field to the real date field) going forward.

Comment: Indeed storing dates as strings is just a lot of work and bugs.

Comment: Yeah the OP added that later.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this (but first backup your table!):

```
UPDATE table SET string_date_field = STR_TO_DATE(string_date_field, "%d-%m-%Y")
WHERE string_date_field RLIKE "^[0-9]{2}-";
```

RLIKE is a synonym of REGEXP and you can use to find the records where the date is in the problematic %d-%m-%Y format. You can afterwards ALTER the table so that the field type is DATE. Also, if your table has a large number of records, maybe you should do this in intervals using a continuous auto-increment field (provided that one exists of course!) to create smaller sets of records for the server to process. For example:

```
UPDATE table SET string_date_field = STR_TO_DATE(string_date_field, "%d-%m-%Y")
WHERE ID >= 1000000 AND ID < 2000000 AND string_date_field RLIKE "^[0-9]{2}-";
```