# what affect date format in mysql?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, date-format

I create asp.net mvc application using mysql as the database in the back end.
But I confused with the way it store the date data.
For e.g. I put 06-03-2012 in the input field, and after saved, in my development computer it will show March 6, 2012 which is exactly what I want, but when I run the application in the server (published application), it will give me; June 3, 2012.
The mysql server both in my development computer and in the server is the same version.

Here is the code I use to get the input:

```
 <tr>
   <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Tanggal)
   </td>
   <td>
       @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Tanggal)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Tanggal)
   </td>
 </tr>
```

What should I do to fix that?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: There are a few things you can look at. First off dates displayed on the MVC pages are set to the culture of the Application. That is by default set to the Dateformat of the application server. To override this you have to set your Application to a specific culture. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Comment: Most applications start with whatever date format is defined in the operating system. In Windows 7, that's in `Control Panel->Clock, Language and Region->Language and Region->Change the date, time, or number format`. Are they defined the same on your local machine and on the server machine? You should also specify the date format you want when you ask for the data; see [updating a date format in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259729/updating-a-date-format-in-mysql); if you ask for it in a specific format, you'll always get it in that format.

Comment: @Ken White: Yes, I have set the exactly the same format both for my development computer and the server. At the time being seems it's not the option to update directly using SQL. But thanks for the info.

Comment: I didn't say anything about "updating using SQL". I mentioned specifically asking for the data in a specific format when doing a `SELECT`, which doesn't update anything; did you actually read the link I posted? :-)

Comment: @Ken White: Yes, sure I read it :), I use LINQ in my app, and still don't know how to 'ported' that format stuff mentioned in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web.config, change the culture :

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" />
```

The globalization is a child node of the system.web node.