# escap character make date value null

Tags: mysql

When I use `-` in date format, it works fine. However, it returns `null` if I used `/`

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2017-04-02',' ', SEC_TO_TIME('45000')),'%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:00 %p')
from cities;
```

Comment: Have you tried // so it escapes and litererals the /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2017-04-02',' ', SEC_TO_TIME('45000')),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00'), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:00 %p')
FROM cities;
```

You have to apply the format mask to the string before to change the date format.
You don't have either AM or PM in the original string, so you have to remove `%p`.

A similar case here: [updating a date format in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259729/updating-a-date-format-in-mysql)